# Continuous scale fill AND categorical fill together

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
>View(gaps)

ID  |  MONTH       |  MEAN  |  CATEGORY
1   |  2012-01-01  |  20    |  No Gap
1   |  2012-02-01  |  30    |  No Gap
1   |  2012-03-01  |  5     |  Gap
2   |  2012-01-01  |  55    |  No Gap
2   |  2012-02-01  |  50    |  No Gap
2   |  2012-03-01  |  55    |  No Gap
```

I would like to plot a heat map that scales continuously using MEAN, and yet I would like to override this fill wherever the CATEGORY value is "Gap", making the tile simple, unvarying, monochrome red.

The set up would be something like this:

```
>p <- ggplot(gaps, aes(x=MONTH, y=ID, fill = MEAN))
>p <- p + geom_tile()
>p <- p + scale_fill_gradient(low="firebrick3", high="darkolivegreen2", space="Lab")
>p
```

Is there a way to then override the fill for instances of "Gap"?  Thanks kindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any genuine `NA` values to worry about, you could set the respective `MEAN` values to `NA`, then specify `na.value` in `scale_fill_gradient`:

```
ggplot(gaps, aes(x=MONTH, y=ID, fill = ifelse(CATEGORY=="Gap", NA, MEAN))) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="firebrick3", high="darkolivegreen2",
                      space="Lab", na.value="red")
```